# How to cache in c#

Tags: c#

```
I have a service method which is getting data from a URL based on the parameters news/blogs.

How to cache the data coming from the URL every 30 minutes?
The user details also get cached for 30 minutes.
Also how do i cache the news,blogs separately if they are coming from the same service URL
```

[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
     public class IITNews : IIITNews
        {
            System.Web.SessionState.HttpSessionState session = HttpContext.Current.Session;
            private static DateTime cacheExpiry = DateTime.MinValue;
            string loggedinUser = "";
            private string cachedResponse = "";

```
 public Stream getNewsBlogsZD(string type, string noOfItems, string devicetype)
        {
            try
            {
                if (cacheExpiry > DateTime.Now)
                {
                    if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache[cachedResponse] != null)
                    {
                        logger.Debug(loggedinUser + "Getting the cached data");
                    }
                    return new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(cachedResponse));
                }
                else
                {

                    string loggedInUserNum = GetEmployeeNumber();
                    string scenarioType = "";
                    string url = "";

                    if (type.Trim().ToUpper() == "NEWS")
                    {
                        scenarioType = "DisplayNews";
                        url = ServiceURL + "getWidgetDetails?WName=News&noOfItems=" + Convert.ToInt32(noOfItems.Trim());
                    }
                    else if (type.Trim().ToUpper() == "ZD")
                    {
                        scenarioType = "DisplayZD";
                        url = ServiceURL + "getWidgetDetails?WName=ZD&noOfItems=" + Convert.ToInt32(noOfItems.Trim());
                    }
                    else if (type.Trim().ToUpper() == "BLOGS")
                    {
                        scenarioType = "DisplayBlogs";
                        url = ServiceURL + "getWidgetDetails?WName=Blogs&noOfItems=" + Convert.ToInt32(noOfItems.Trim());
                    }

                    WebClient client = new WebClient();


                    client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                    client.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
                    cachedResponse = client.DownloadString(url);

 HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert("cacheResponse",cachedResponse ,null);

                    cacheExpiry = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30);
                    return new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(cachedResponse));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
             string message=ex.message;
                return new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("[]"));
            }

        }

public stream userdertails
{
//method to fetch user details where no cache is used
}

}
```

Comment: Use a global variable and a timer...

Comment: Can you please share the code.I am new to this.

Comment: To be able to provide a comprehensive answer, 'readers' will need to know a bit more about your application....Is it an EXE, Web Service, website, etc

Comment: It is wcf service

Comment: Side note: Empty catch-all exception handlers are a famously bad idea.  If your code is ever failing in some way, you are *explicitly* telling the code to completely ignore the problem.  This will make failures difficult to diagnose.

Answer (score 0):

If this is your service, you can cache it on the service and return same data for very same parameters.

If not, you can create some singleton class to hold data in. If the singleton has valid data, return them instead of calling WebService :)

Comment: Hi David I am trying to use something like this
Cache.Insert("AbsoluteCacheKey", client, null,
DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30),
System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);

For reading data from cache.

if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache[ALLDEFAULTLINKSCACHE] != null)
                    {
                        dsListBoxItems = (DataSet)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache[ALLDEFAULTLINKSCACHE];
                       
                        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache.Remove(ALLDEFAULTLINKSCACHE);
                    }
This is not working.Could you please suggest

Comment: @ShagunSingh Rather than placing unformatted code in comments, why not add this evidence to your question with a little more info than "This is not working".

Answer (score 0):

Store the result somewhere, along with a time stamp.  Where you store it is up to you.  There are a variety of caching systems you can find, there's a database, there's the file system, in-memory static values, instance values, etc., etc.

Possibly the simplest approach would just be a class-level value.  Something like this:

```
private string cachedResponse = "";
private DateTime cacheExpiry = DateTime.MinValue;
```

Then in your logic you would check for the cache before deciding to query the service.  Something like this:

```
if (cacheExpiry > DateTime.Now)
    return new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(cachedResponse));

// the rest of your method to query the service
// then...

cachedResponse = client.DownloadString(url);
cacheExpiry = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30);

return new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(cachedResponse));
```

This is just an example of the logic behind the *concept* of a cache, of course.  If your object instance itself doesn't remain in memory then this object-level cache of course wouldn't do the job.  The *logic* is always the same:

1. Check if the cache is still valid.
2. If so, return the cached value.
3. If not, query the service and store the new value and update the cache expiry and return the newly cached value.

Where you *store* the cache is up to you and depends on more than what's present in this question.

Comment: Hi I am trying to cache in the following way:-

Comment: [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]


private string cachedResponse = "";
private DateTime cacheExpiry = DateTime.MinValue;

Comment: @ShagunSingh: Ok.... And did you have a question about that?  Is something not working?

Comment: Hi @David
Yes I have an issue that in page all the service methods are getting cached.
For eg:-There is a user details method that gets cached too.
How can i cache the data only for one method.

Comment: @ShagunSingh: The proposed solution in this answer wouldn’t cache everything by default, it would only cache what you explicitly store in the cache storage.  What are you storing there?  Where do you store it?  Include your updated code in the question.

Comment: Hi @David,I am trying to use in memory cache.Posted the latest code as question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [MemoryCache Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache(v=vs.110).aspx) which enables you to cache objects and set time of them to live in cache.